# What regex syntax does Tensorboard support for tag and run filtering?

Tags: regex, tensorboard, regex-negation

I would like to filter tags with a specific regex. In my case, I'd like to negate a character in the search. I cannot find any README, resources, or github issue that discusses what regex syntax Tensorboard 1.15 supports.

Comment: Since it is used in the browser, it must be the browser-based JavaScript regex. It is easy to check: try `[^]+` - and if it selects all tags, it is ECMAScript regex.

Comment: It looks like [^] has no affect -- I cannot get it to filter out a simple alphabetical character (e.g. 'k') from the tags, using `[^k]`

Comment: No, `[^]+` matches any string in full, that is what I meant. `[^k]` works in any regex flavor.

Comment: Let me rephrase. `[^]+` matches all strings, although tensorboard has some strange behavior when regex fails, in that it will often return all strings. So it is not clear if the `[^]+` regex is successful or not. `[^k]+` also returns all strings, including those that contain a 'k'

Answer (score 1):

Guessing by the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master) of Tensorboard, it's using Python's own re module, and the `_create_regexp_filter(regex)` function specifically uses [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). That means it will

> Scan through (the) string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match

Therefore, to exclude *tags* (or *runs*) that contain a specific character you need a regex that fails when there is any occurrence. A common pattern to achieve this, e.g. exclude all tags that contain the letter `k`, is this (for a single character or a character group)

```
^[^k]+$
```

or this (to exclude phrases)

```
^((?!k).)+$
```

Comment: Ups, this was an old question. For some reason, I showed up in my queue. Oh, well one unanswered Q less on SO. :D